# How do you find text using w3m?

Tags: w3m

I would like to be able to find a word in a web page using [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/).

On most browsers I can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find a word.

I know this can be done on [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL) but Google has decided to not provide any results today, and I don't see anything on the manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL which shows to do <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the manpage here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/w3m

Comment: @mchid Yeahbut, I learned that's OK, sometimes, but not always accurate. Ubuntu's man page https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+man+w3m+bionic pointed me at http://w3m.sourceforge.net/ which led me to the manual, which was less user-hostile.  Ubuntu's man pages tend to be more useful, IMHO, and when your rasslin' with the Google, telling it "Hey! Look Over There!" is kinda useful.